# XAML ListBoxItem Gradient Color Animation

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Am having a problem setting the gradient background of the selected listviewitem. Everytime I select the item, it spits an error.

here's my generic.xaml partian code

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#577E7E7E" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[0].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#C6FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[1].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Best,
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Type.Background).GradientStops[0].Color"